# Android FragmentTransaction commit already called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

My ERROR :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

My CODE:

```
final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

f1_fragment  = new F1_Fragments();
f2_fragment = new F2_Fragments();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            if(position==0){
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f1_fragment);
            }else{
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f2_fragment);
            }

            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you already made a commit on that transaction, you need to start a new transaction if you want to make a commit again `fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

Answer (score 71):

You are beginning the FragmentTransaction outside of the `OnItemClickListener`. Thus you are attempting to `commit()` a single FragmentTransaction every time the user clicks an item in your ListView.

You need to begin a new FragmentTransaction every time you intend to perform any number of Fragment operations.

A simple fix would look like this:

```
f1_fragment  = new F1_Fragments();
f2_fragment = new F2_Fragments();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        if(position==0){
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f1_fragment);
        }else{
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f2_fragment);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!

is there a best way to do this? im implementing the Listview in SlidingMenu.

Comment: From what I can see, the pattern you are using looks fine.

Comment: it works for me. I really appreciate your help. thanks.

Answer (score 11):

you can use this method for replace fragment with each other just call this

do those are global

```
YourFragment1 frg1 = new   YourFragment1 ();    
YourFragment2 frg1 = new   YourFragment2 ();
```

And then call it by

```
openFragment(frg1);
```

or

```
  openFragment(frg2);
```

**OpenFragment:**

```
  private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment)   {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();        
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: thanks, and also making `fragmentManager` a private field is a better idea :)

Answer (score 7):

Look at this scenario

I need to add new fragment on every list item click. Just **initialise fragment transaction** on every item click.

```
switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.tvaddExpense:

                    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerFucntionsList, new Fragment1());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;

                case R.id.relEvents:
                    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerFucntionsList, new Fragment2());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue and I have solved by creating **new instance** of `FragmentTransaction`.

Just add **everytime** below line before **add** / **replace** fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 5):

The Error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

shows that the `FragmentTransaction` has been completed after calling `commit()` the first time and you are again calling `commit()` which tends to complete it once again. Hence it makes an Illegal state for  the `FragmentTransaction`.

As per your code, you are using the same `FragmentTransaction` for changing fragments. However, after the first `commit()` call, the `FragmentTransaction` has completed and you need to begin it again to perform any operation on `Fragments`.

You can change your `ClickListner` as:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   

            parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            if(position==0){
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f1_fragment);
            }else{
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f2_fragment);
            }

            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

I hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 4):

You must define a FragmentTransAction object separately each time you add a fragment:

```
     switch (position){
                case 0:
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.parentOfMenu, new FragmentHome());
                    fragmentTransaction1.commit();

                    break;
                case 1:
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.parentOfMenu, new FragmentMedia());
                    fragmentTransaction2.commit();

                    break;

                case 2:
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.parentOfMenu, new FragmentChart());
                    fragmentTransaction3.commit();

                    break;

                case 3:
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.parentOfMenu, new FragmentProfile());
                    fragmentTransaction4.commit();

                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue 
after calling `commit()` and again replacing the fragment you should start from

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

if(position==0){
     fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f1_fragment);
 else{
     fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f2_fragment);
 }

 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```