# Android Studio - Error: Commit already called

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment, commit, android-framelayout

I am suffering from this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:669)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
    at com.example.ui.PACK.SUBPACK.subpack$4.onClick(subpack.java:94)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

**This is my JAVA code:**

```
public class subpack extends Fragment {

private FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subpack, container, false);

ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//TXT LUNES EVENT LISTENER
    txt_lunes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){  
            fragment = new lunes_gestionar();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
    });

    //TXT MARTES EVENT LISTENER
    txt_martes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            fragment = new martes_gestionar();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
    });
```

**Description:**

I have a fragment with another fragment inside in wich TEXT VIEWS (Monday an Tuesday) are used to change fragment with **Fragment Transaction**. The problem is when i click on this text views for second time.

How can i solve this?

**Thanks so much for reading!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android FragmentTransaction commit already called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561874/android-fragmenttransaction-commit-already-called)

Comment: No, it doesn´t. My sittuation is different because i am changing fragments from click listeners!

Comment: you already made a commit on that transaction, you need to start a new transaction if you want to make a commit again `fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 txt_lunes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){  
            fragment = new lunes_gestionar();

            FragmentTransaction ft =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();     
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
    });


txt_martes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            fragment = new martes_gestionar();

            FragmentTransaction ft =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro! You solved my problem. Could you please explain me why this worked?

Comment: The error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called` shows that the `FragmentTransaction` has been completed after calling `commit()` the first time and you are again calling `commit()` which tends to complete it once again. Hence it makes an Illegal state for the `FragmentTransaction`.

As per your code, you are using the same `FragmentTransaction` for changing fragments. However, after the first `commit()` call, the `FragmentTransaction` has completed and you need to begin it again to perform any operation on Fragments.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35177755/7972851)

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to just have 1 beginTransaction(), You should use beginTransaction() before each replacement.

Use this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace() ...
```